# Incompatible redefinition of macro

Tags: c, macros, arm, redefinition

When I compile my c project with make command, there is the error

> Error:  #47-D: incompatible redefinition of macro "MACRO_NAME"

It looks like MACRO_NAME is already defined in one of the header files, but I want to redefine or hardcode new value for MACRO_NAME.

How to remove this error?

Comment: Do you know what the *original* definition is doing? And how redefining will affect it?

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of the original definition. And the header file is a temporary one with hardcoded values

Comment: what toolchain?  why is this tagged as arm?  please provide a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (all the source code required and command line commands that minimally demonstrate the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no clean way to define this macro so that it realiably and predictably is not used in the meaning of one of the definitions, when the other one is meant.

If you use a mechanism with `undef`, then you run the risk to undefine the other meaning, define it to your meaning and then end up with code which expects the other meaning seeing and using your meaning.

The only way to achieve reliability and predictability is to make sure that code which expects one meaning does not include (neither directly nor indirectly) the header which defines the other meaning.

You can do so by

a) defining in a way that neither definition can be done when the other one is already defined. To do so, in both cases

```c
#ifdef MACRO_NAME
#error Separation of the two meanings of MACRO_NAME failed!
/* the other definition of MACRO_NAME is alreay visible */
#endif

#define MACRO_NAME MyMeaning
```

b) make sure that no code includes both definitions

Actually a) is only a technical help to make sure b). If you say that you will not ever include both definitions into one code file, then you have no problem. In that case, you do not get the `#error` from a). In that case you do not have a problem with using the wrong definition. Good. How do you know? How can you be sure that you do not have the problem, even if you change code, even if your colleague changes code? Use a), then you will be clearly told when you get caught by the redefinition trap. If you use `#undef` instead, then you have not prevented the problem, just hidden it and made it harder to debug.

c) in the case that you can only influence one of the two definitions, i.e. the other one is by another supplier, the best way is to change the name of your own definition. Whatever effort that causes in your code, it will be less than getting caught be unintended redefinition problems.

d) in the case that you cannot influence any of the two definitions (which is of course NOT the case you are asking about) you have to separate the code files into two groups, those who use one definition and not the other and the group which uses the other definition and only that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use #undef to redefine MACRO in the header file when it is needed

```
#ifdef MACRO_NAME
#undef MACRO_NAME
#endif
#define MACRO_NAME 100
```

Comment: Is the `#endif` in the right place? Or should it be moved up one line?

Comment: Good question, #endif can be in either before or after new #define.

#undef can be used even without #ifdef, if we know for sure MACRO_NAME is already defined.

Comment: Yes, it can, but you won't get the definition.

Comment: No, it most definitely needs to get moved, otherwise the redefinition won't happen.

Comment: Well, the *re*definition will happen, but not an original one.

Comment: Is `ifdef` even needed? What will happen to `#undef` if not defined?

Comment: The `#ifdef` serves no purpose. It is okay to `#undef` a name that doesn't exist. This is commonly done to reveal a real function definition of a C library function that may or may not be a macro; e.g. `#undef getc`.

Comment: @Kaz More like "The `#ifdef` is not needed".  As with such style issues, 1) defer to the group's style guide. 2) else code to what provides clarity for that situation.